# Mysql full text serach order by field ( not score ) performance speed up

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, full-text-search

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM search_table 
WHERE MATCH(field1,field2,field3,fieldx) 
AGAINST ('+string1 +string2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

field1,field2,fieldx are indexed for fulltext. The query runs fast with 50k record. Something like 0.001

I need to order by field1,field2 etc. But when I add ORDER BY field1 like this:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM search_table 
WHERE MATCH(field1,field2,field3,fieldx) 
AGAINST ('+string1 +string2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY field1 ASC
```

the speed drops to 0.1 . How can i speed up this query? I tried to add an index to field1 but its still slow.

Comment: cant you sort it your application code if possible?

Comment: I dont want to work with 50-100k row in the application code only if no way to speed up the query.